# How to permanently append a directory to PYTHON PATH on Mac

Tags: terminal, python

I tried the two common methods:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('foo/bar')
```

AND

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:foo/bar
```

The first one terminates the appendage once interpreter is exited. The second terminates when terminal is closed (despite the fact that people seem to have no problem with permanently appending via the second method).

What am I missing here and how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put

```
foo/bar
```

In a file inside etc/paths.d.

[here is a good explanation](http://willbryant.net/software/mac_os_x/paths)

EDIT: I think I miss understood, you want to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable. 
[this link](http://www.semioticpixels.com/crib-notes/mac-10-7-path-settings-and-environment-variables/) show many places that you could put you export statement so it would be permanent.

Put

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:foo/bar
```

In ~/.bashrc and it will be set every time bash starts.

Comment: can you please explain how exactly I can do this in the terminal? I am a beginner.

Comment: 'vi ~/.bashrc' then type 'i' to start inserting. Type the export line. Hit escape, colen, wq. That will save the file. Restart the terminal. You can check if it worked by typing 'echo $PYTHONPATH'